# Is the Galois action on $m$-torsion of an elliptic curve transitive?

Tags: galois-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

The question basically says it all - there is of course a natural action of $G_{\overline{K} / K}$ on $E[m]$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $K$ and $E[m]$ is the $m$-torsion subgroup of that curve. My question is whether this action is transitive.

This seems like a natural question, but I haven't been able to find anything that addresses the question directly.

Comment: What if every $m$-torsion point of $E$ is defined over $K$? Then the action of $G_{\overline{K}/K}$ is trivial.

Comment: Fair enough... I guess what I'm looking for will require some additional hypotheses somewhere, thanks!

Comment: Another easy constraint: if $d \mid m$, then the subgroup $E[d]$ of $E[m]$ is stable under the Galois action. So no point of $E[d]$ can be sent to a point in $E[m] \setminus E[d]$.

Comment: I don't think transitivity is what you really mean to ask: otherwise, the answer is trivially no. $0$ is always sent to $0$, and no other element is sent to $0$, so...

Comment: I feel like what you really want to ask is more like: is there a non-trivial (i.e. not equal to $E[d]$ for $d\mid m$ Galois stable subgroup of $E[m]$. And the answer is yes, if and only if $E$ admits a cyclic $p$-isogeny for some $p\mid m$. Alternatively, you could ask the very natural question of whether the induced homomorphism $G_K\to \mathrm{GL}(E[m])$ is surjective... this question has been extensively studied!